# Nav2 | Accurate path following for Ackermann in narrow corridors (ROS2 Iron)

Tags: ros2, nav2

I've been trying to get an Ackermann tricycle to navigate smoothly through narrow corridors. However, the robot doesn't seem to follow the planner's path correctly in my simulation environment. My robot moves perfectly forwards and backwards in the narrow corridors, but when it comes to turning, it deviates greatly from the path generated by the planner, often ending up in awkward manoeuvres or bumping into the near walls [(Video)](https://imgur.com/a/jXVIUuD).

I am using MPPI controller with Smac Hybrid planner. I've tried tuning the Obstacle and PathAlign critics but I am not able to achieve better performance.

Here is my current params file:

```
amcl:
 ros__parameters:
  use_sim_time: False
  alpha1: 0.2
  alpha2: 0.2
  alpha3: 0.2
  alpha4: 0.2
  alpha5: 0.2
  base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
  beam_skip_distance: 0.5
  beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
  beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
  do_beamskip: false
  global_frame_id: "map"
  lambda_short: 0.1
  laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
  laser_max_range: 100.0
  laser_min_range: -1.0
  laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
  max_beams: 60
  max_particles: 2000
  min_particles: 500
  odom_frame_id: "odom"
  pf_err: 0.05
  pf_z: 0.99
  recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
  recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
  resample_interval: 1
  robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::OmniMotionModel"
  save_pose_rate: 0.5
  sigma_hit: 0.2
  tf_broadcast: true
  transform_tolerance: 1.0
  update_min_a: 0.2
  update_min_d: 0.25
  z_hit: 0.5
  z_max: 0.05
  z_rand: 0.5
  z_short: 0.05
  scan_topic: /laser1

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    navigators: ["navigate_to_pose", "navigate_through_poses"]
    navigate_to_pose:
      plugin: "nav2_bt_navigator/NavigateToPoseNavigator"
    navigate_through_poses:
      plugin: "nav2_bt_navigator/NavigateThroughPosesNavigator"
    # 'default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml' and 'default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml' are use defaults:
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_to_pose_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # They can be set here or via a RewrittenYaml remap from a parent launch file to Nav2.
    plugin_lib_names:
      - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_smooth_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_action_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_bt_node
      - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
      - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_globally_updated_goal_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_is_path_valid_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_are_error_codes_active_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_would_a_controller_recovery_help_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_would_a_planner_recovery_help_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_would_a_smoother_recovery_help_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
      - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_local_action_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
      - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
      - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
      - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
      - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_path_expiring_timer_condition
      - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
      - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_path_longer_on_approach_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_charging_condition_bt_node
    error_code_names:
      - compute_path_error_code
      - follow_path_error_code

bt_navigator_navigate_through_poses_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    controller_frequency: 30.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 10.0
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.035
    failure_tolerance: 0.0
    odom_topic: "odom"
    progress_checker_plugins: ["progress_checker"] # progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker" For Humble and older
    goal_checker_plugins: ["goal_checker"] # goal_checker_plugin: "goal_checker" For Galactic and older
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    goal_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      stateful: True
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "nav2_mppi_controller::MPPIController"
      time_steps: 56
      model_dt: 0.05
      batch_size: 2000
      vx_std: 0.2
      vy_std: 0.0
      wz_std: 0.4
      vx_max: 3.0
      vx_min: -3.0
      vy_max: 0.0
      vy_min: 0.0
      wz_min: -3.0
      wz_max: 3.0
      iteration_count: 1
      prune_distance: 1.0
      transform_tolerance: 0.1
      temperature: 0.3
      gamma: 0.015
      motion_model: "Ackermann"
      visualize: false
      #reset_period: 1.0 # (only in Humble)
      regenerate_noises: false
      TrajectoryVisualizer:
        trajectory_step: 5
        time_step: 3
      AckermannConstraints:
        min_turning_r: 1.0
      critics: ["ConstraintCritic", ObstaclesCritic, "GoalCritic", "GoalAngleCritic", "PathAlignCritic", "PathFollowCritic", "PathAngleCritic"]
      ConstraintCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 4.0
      GoalCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        threshold_to_consider: 1.4
      GoalAngleCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 3.0
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
      #PreferForwardCritic:
      #  enabled: true
      #  cost_power: 1
      #  cost_weight: 5.0
      #  threshold_to_consider: 0.5
      ObstaclesCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        repulsion_weight: 1.7
        critical_weight: 20.0
        consider_footprint: true
        collision_cost: 10000.0
        collision_margin_distance: 0.1
        near_goal_distance: 0.5
      PathAlignCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 20.0
        max_path_occupancy_ratio: 0.05
        trajectory_point_step: 3
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
        offset_from_furthest: 20
        use_path_orientations: false
      PathFollowCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        offset_from_furthest: 5
        threshold_to_consider: 1.4
      PathAngleCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 2.0
        offset_from_furthest: 20
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
        max_angle_to_furthest: 1.0
        mode: 1
      # TwirlingCritic:
      #   enabled: true
      #   twirling_cost_power: 1
      #   twirling_cost_weight: 10.0

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      map_topic: "/local_costmap/costmap" 
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
      rolling_window: true
      width: 9
      height: 9
      resolution: 0.05
      #robot_radius: 1.0
      footprint: "[ [-0.35, 0.43], [1.00, 0.43], [1.40, 0.30], [1.40, -0.30], [1.00, -0.43], [-0.35, -0.43] ]"
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.4
        inflation_radius: 1.5
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        #footprint_clearing_enabled: True
        observation_sources: laser1
        laser1:
          topic: /laser1
          max_obstacle_height: 1.6
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 20.0
          raytrace_min_range: 1.0
          obstacle_max_range: 20.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.30
      always_send_full_costmap: False
  

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      map_topic: "/global_costmap/costmap"   # JLBC
      origin_x: -15.0
      origin_y: -15.0
      width: 60
      height: 60
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
      #robot_radius: 0.4
      footprint: "[ [-0.35, 0.43], [1.00, 0.43], [1.40, 0.30], [1.40, -0.30], [1.00, -0.43], [-0.35, -0.43] ]"
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        #footprint_clearing_enabled: True
        observation_sources: laser1
        laser1:
          topic: /laser1
          max_obstacle_height: 1.6
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 20.0
          raytrace_min_range: 1.0
          obstacle_max_range: 20.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.30
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.4
        inflation_radius: 1.5
      always_send_full_costmap: False

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    # Overridden in launch by the "map" launch configuration or provided default value.
    # To use in yaml, remove the default "map" value in the tb3_simulation_launch.py file & provide full path to map below.
    yaml_filename: ""

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: False
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_smac_planner/SmacPlannerHybrid"
      downsample_costmap: false                     # whether or not to downsample the map
      downsampling_factor: 1                        # multiplier for the resolution of the costmap layer (e.g. 2 on a 5cm costmap would be 10cm)
      tolerance: 0.25                               # dist-to-goal heuristic cost (distance) for valid tolerance endpoints if exact goal cannot be found.
      allow_unknown: true                           # allow traveling in unknown space
      max_iterations: 1000000                       # maximum total iterations to search for before failing (in case unreachable), set to -1 to disable
      max_on_approach_iterations: 1000              # Maximum number of iterations after within tolerances to continue to try to find exact solution
      max_planning_time: 5.0                        # max time in s for planner to plan, smooth
      motion_model_for_search: "REEDS_SHEPP"        # Hybrid-A* Dubin, Redds-Shepp
      angle_quantization_bins: 72                   # Number of angle bins for search
      analytic_expansion_ratio: 3.5                 # The ratio to attempt analytic expansions during search for final approach.
      analytic_expansion_max_length: 3.0            # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: The maximum length of the analytic expansion to be considered valid to prevent unsafe shortcutting
      analytic_expansion_max_cost: 200.0            # The maximum single cost for any part of an analytic expansion to contain and be valid, except when necessary on approach to goal
      analytic_expansion_max_cost_override: false   #  Whether or not to override the maximum cost setting if within critical distance to goal (ie probably required)
      minimum_turning_radius: 1.00                  # minimum turning radius in m of path / vehicle
      reverse_penalty: 2.0                          # Penalty to apply if motion is reversing, must be => 1
      change_penalty: 0.0                           # Penalty to apply if motion is changing directions (L to R), must be >= 0
      non_straight_penalty: 1.2                     # Penalty to apply if motion is non-straight, must be => 1
      cost_penalty: 2.0                             # Penalty to apply to higher cost areas when adding into the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic. This drives the robot more towards the center of passages. A value between 1.3 - 3.5 is reasonable.
      retrospective_penalty: 0.015
      lookup_table_size: 20.0                       # Size of the dubin/reeds-sheep distance window to cache, in meters.
      cache_obstacle_heuristic: false               # Cache the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic between subsiquent replannings of the same goal location. Dramatically speeds up replanning performance (40x) if costmap is largely static.
      debug_visualizations: false                   # For Hybrid nodes: Whether to publish expansions on the /expansions topic as an array of poses (the orientation has no meaning) and the path's footprints on the /planned_footprints topic. WARNING: heavy to compute and to display, for debug only as it degrades the performance.
      use_quadratic_cost_penalty: False
      downsample_obstacle_heuristic: True
      allow_primitive_interpolation: False
      smooth_path: True                             # If true, does a simple and quick smoothing post-processing to the path
      smoother:
        max_iterations: 1000
       w_smooth: 0.3
        w_data: 0.2
        tolerance: 1.0e-10
        do_refinement: true
        refinement_num: 2

smoother_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    smoother_plugins: ["SmoothPath"]
    SmoothPath:
      plugin: "nav2_constrained_smoother/ConstrainedSmoother"
      reversing_enabled: true       # whether to detect forward/reverse direction and cusps. Should be set to false for paths without orientations assigned
      path_downsampling_factor: 3   # every n-th node of the path is taken. Useful for speed-up
      path_upsampling_factor: 1     # 0 - path remains downsampled, 1 - path is upsampled back to original granularity using cubic bezier, 2... - more upsampling
      keep_start_orientation: true  # whether to prevent the start orientation from being smoothed
      keep_goal_orientation: true   # whether to prevent the gpal orientation from being smoothed
      minimum_turning_radius: 1.00  # minimum turning radius the robot can perform. Can be set to 0.0 (or w_curve can be set to 0.0 with the same effect) for diff-drive/holonomic robots
      w_curve: 30.0                 # weight to enforce minimum_turning_radius
      w_dist: 0.0                   # weight to bind path to original as optional replacement for cost weight
      w_smooth: 2000000.0           # weight to maximize smoothness of path
      w_cost: 0.015                 # weight to steer robot away from collision and cost
      # Parameters used to improve obstacle avoidance near cusps (forward/reverse movement changes)
      w_cost_cusp_multiplier: 3.0   # option to use higher weight during forward/reverse direction change which is often accompanied with dangerous rotations
      cusp_zone_length: 2.5         # length of the section around cusp in which nodes use w_cost_cusp_multiplier (w_cost rises gradually inside the zone towards the cusp point, whose costmap weight eqals w_cost*w_cost_cusp_multiplier)
      # Points in robot frame to grab costmap values from. Format: [x1, y1, weight1, x2, y2, weight2, ...]
      # IMPORTANT: Requires much higher number of iterations to actually improve the path. Uncomment only if you really need it (highly elongated/asymmetric robots)
      # cost_check_points: [-0.185, 0.0, 1.0]
      optimizer:
        max_iterations: 70            # max iterations of smoother
        debug_optimizer: false        # print debug info
        optimizer.linear_solver_type: “SPARSE_NORMAL_CHOLESKY” # "DENSE_QR"
        gradient_tol: 1.0e-10
        fn_tol: 1.0e-15
        param_tol: 1.0e-20

behavior_server:
  ros__parameters:
    local_costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    global_costmap_topic: global_costmap/costmap_raw
    local_footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    global_footprint_topic: global_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    behavior_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "drive_on_heading", "assisted_teleop", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/BackUp"
    drive_on_heading:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Wait"
    assisted_teleop:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/AssistedTeleop"
    local_frame: odom
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_tolerance: 0.1
    use_sim_time: False
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    loop_rate: 20
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200

velocity_smoother:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    smoothing_frequency: 20.0
    scale_velocities: False
    feedback: "OPEN_LOOP"
    max_velocity: [3.00, 0.0, 3.0]
    min_velocity: [-3.00, 0.0, -3.0]
    max_accel: [2.5, 0.0, 3.2]
    max_decel: [-2.5, 0.0, -3.2]
    odom_topic: "odom"
    odom_duration: 0.1
    deadband_velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity_timeout: 1.0
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?